# How can I add dynamic field in the model in django?

Tags: python, database, django

I'm using django to create a application download site. I try to write a model, that the admin can add the different download content dynamically in the admin page. For example I have a software named foobar, it have 3 different version: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3. I would like the user can admin the model by using an add button to add the download link with a download version. But I don't know how to do this in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your models to have a main model and ancillary models that have foreign keys to the main model:

```
class DownloadItem(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField( etc etc)
   ... other attributes here ...


class DownloadItemFile(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey('DownloadItem', related_name="versions")
   version = models.CharField( etc etc)
   file = models.FileField(upload='path/to/uploaddir/')
```

then, when you have an instance of your DownloadItem model, you can get hold of your various file versions with:

```
mydownloaditem.versions.all()
```

To be able to add files via the Admin, you will need to use an inline. In your admin.py for the app in question, you'll need to add something like:

```
class DownloadItemFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model           = DownloadItemFile

class DownloadItemAdminOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines         = [ DownloadItemFileInline, ]
    ...other admin options here...    

admin.site.register(DownloadItem, DownloadItem AdminOptions)
```

Comment: Hello stevejalim:
 Thanks for your answer. It works. But when I go to the admin page, add the "DownloadItem", How can I show the versions including in it? and how can I directly add a DownloadItemFile in DownloadItem page?